# My C program's output is not the expected one

Tags: c, output, character, variable-assignment

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   char c, p;
   p=getchar();
   int n=p+259;
   c=n;
   putchar(c);
   return 0;
}
```

If I input the 'a' character, could someone tell me why this program's output is the 'd' character?

If p='a', then n=97+259=356.
How is it possible to assign to c the value 100(ASCII code for 'd') if my n variable is 356?

Comment: Check your types. `char` rolls over to 0 once it reaches 255.

Comment: @RPGillespie and what if `char` is signed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char` is an 8bit data type, and you greatly exceeded its max representation:

```
a -> ascii 97
97 + 259 -> 356
356 & 0xFF -> 100 - overflowed, strip off "high bit" which can't be stored.
100 -> ascii 'd'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation!.And I think 356 & 0xFF -> 100.

Answer (score 5):

`char` can take values from 0 to 255 because it's 8 bit.

97 + 259 = 356 and 356 modulo 256 is 100.

Comment: Ok.I got it.Thank you very much!